# Find and update dynamic values MongoDB

Tags: javascript, database, mongodb, discord, chatbot

I'm coding a **Discord bot** in **java script** right now. I use **MongoDB** to store a "heat" value for every user in my server. (The "heat-system" adds a certain amount to a percentage whenever the user does something wrong and takes it off again after some time, to be more specific: **-5 percent every minute** in my example).

To do that, I want to use `Model.updateMany()` in a loop. As you see below, I used the filter parameter to find every document related to my server. The question now is **how I can take these 5% off the stored value** because it's not static, but dynamic.

```js
    const { Client } = require('discord.js');
    const mongoose = require('mongoose');
    //using modules and event handlers
    module.exports = {
        name: 'ready',
        /**
         * @param {Client} client
         */
        async execute(client) {
            const heatdb = require('/app/models/heatDB.js');
            //how often the loop should pe repeated
            const interval = 10 * 60 * 1000;
            console.log('Client ready.')
            //connnecting my data
            mongoose.connect(
                'I put the mongoose link here', {
                    useNewUrlParser: true,
                    useUnifiedTopology: true
            }).then(() => {
                console.log('Data connected.')
            }).catch((err) => {
                console.log(err)
            });
            //loop begins here
            setInterval(function(){
                //filtered so that it's only searching for documents having the guild ID in it
                heatdb.updateMany({ GuildID: "000000000000000000"}, {Heat: parseInt(/*needed value*/) - 5}})
            }, interval);
        },
    };
```

And also see how my model is built below:

```js
    const { Schema, model } = require('mongoose');

    module.exports = model("heatDB", new Schema({
        GuildID: String,
        UserID: String,
        Heat: String,
    }))
```

If you need anything else to help me, please let me know.

Thank you in advance,

Hydra

Comment: is this 5 percent is dynamic or it may change to any percent right?

Comment: You can use findoneAndUpdate method to update a particular document based on GuildID.

Comment: @GulshanAggarwal Yes, the percentage may change depending on the user's behaviour. So you never know it's value as a static variable.

And no, there's more than one document, every user has its own in the collection, that's why I think that I can't use "findOne..."

Comment: I need the old value to take the 5% off, but I don't know how to define it

Comment: I think there is confusion, let me explain- every user has a unique GuildID, UserID, and Heat right?  Then you just need to find the document with that GuildID and update its heat?  Please explain more so I can help you?

Comment: Okay: there's a collection with many documents in it, one for every user in my server. They all have different "heat" values and user ID's so I filter with the guild ID to only get the documents with the guild ID in it. So I need a function to update many documents. The question is how I get the old value from every user's document to subtract 5%. But you're right, the user ID and heat value both are unique

Comment: if you can change your Heat value to a Number type instead of a String inside your  Schema, then you can try the solution I have posted.

Comment: I hope this will work for you. Thank you!

Comment: `-5` is different to "take 5% off" Maybe start with a clear definition of your requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your Heat value is a Number in Schema instead of String then you can try this-

```js
heatdb.updateMany({ GuildID: "000000000000000000"},{$mul:{"Heat":0.95}})
```

**Explanation:-** you want to reduce Heat every time 5% percent then you can use `mul`
operator & set your heat value to 95% of current value. It will give you 5% deduction every time.

Comment: Thanks, @PlexHydra & don't you think we should connect socially?

Comment: we can, I'm mostly active on Discord (PlexHydra#5574) and Twitter (@plexhydra), suggest another platform if you want

Comment: let's connect on Twitter